# Keyboard navigation for clickable header tag

Tags: html, wai-aria

I am having some trouble accessing a navigable header item using my keyboard and i wanted to know if i am miss using ARIA and if i should label or mark them differently in order for me to be able to navigate to the header link using the keyboard as opposed to the keyboard.

```
<article role="article">
    <header role="navigation" data-bind="click:gotoLink">
        <div>....</div>
    </header>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what you are trying to acheive from your code sample, but some things to note:

- it does not make sense to override a `header` element with a `navigation` role and it is [non-conforming in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/) to do so.
- In order for an element to be navigable via the keyboard it requires that it either be [interactive content](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#interactive-content) or have a [`tabindex` attribute](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/) added.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful facts. What i am trying to do is to have my header navigable so when i am using my keyboard and focus is on the header i want to be able to press enter and navigate to its content page. I am able to do this by a mouse click but i currently with the keyboard and focus on it - i am not able to navigate.

Comment: or even that whole article tag